# Error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: javascript, php, sql, highcharts

Estoy utilizando PHP, y JavaScript junto con la librería highcharts para generar un gráfico de barras, pero me aparece el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\graficos\index.php on line 55

Lo que quiero es pasar el resultado de la consulta a una variable, para que ésta luego pueda mostrarse en una tabla y de esta forma generar el gráfico. Les dejo mi código:

**La conexión**

```
<?php
 class Conexion
 {
   var $conexion;
   function Conexion()
   {
     $this->conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","futuro"); 
   }
 }
?>
```

**Index**

```
<?php

    require_once("clases/conexion.php");
        $objeto=new Conexion;
?>

<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Grafico Comparativo de Ventas Anuales por Sucursal</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
 ${demo.css}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
 $('#container').highcharts({
    data: {
        table: 'datatable'
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Grafico Comparativo de Ventas Anuales por Sucursal'
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Millones'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
        }
       }
      });
     });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <?php 

    $sql="SELECT SUM(detalle_boleta.costo) FROM detalle_boleta INNER JOIN      venta_boleta ON detalle_boleta.numero_bol = venta_boleta.numero_bol
    WHERE venta_boleta.fecha_bol BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'";
    $enero1=mysqli_query($this->conexion,$sql);


                    ?>
  <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

  <table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>2015</th>
        <th>2016</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Enero</th>
        <td><?php echo '$enero1' ; ?></td>
        <td>42500000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Febrero</th>
        <td>40000000</td>
        <td>42500000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Marzo</th>
        <td>40000000</td>
        <td>42500000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Abril</th>
        <td>40000000</td>
        <td>42500000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Mayo</th>
        <td>40000000</td>
        <td>42500000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Junio</th>
        <td>40000000</td>
        <td>42500000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Julio</th>
        <td>40000000</td>
        <td>42500000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Agosto</th>
        <td>40000000</td>
        <td>42500000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Septiembre</th>
        <td>40000000</td>
        <td>42500000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Octubre</th>
        <td>40000000</td>
        <td>42500000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Noviembre</th>
        <td>40000000</td>
        <td>42500000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Diciembre</th>
        <td>40000000</td>
        <td>42500000</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Linea 55**

La línea que tiene el problema está luego de la consulta, la cual seria:

```
$enero1=mysqli_query($this->conexion,$sql);
```

No estoy seguro de si el problema es cómo estoy haciendo la conexión, ya apenas hoy comencé a utilizar highchart.

Comment: En php 5, el uso de `var` como modificador de visibilidad sinónimo de `public` está soportado por motivos de retrocompatibilidad, pero su uso se desaconseja por razones de legibilidad. Puedes leer más información [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visibility-members)

Answer (score 1):

El problema es porque `$this` está ya en otro archivo y fuera de la clase Conexion, dentro de la clase puedes usar `$this` porque hace referencia a la misma clase para usar las variables y funciones dentro de ella, pero fuera de la clase lo que debes hacer es instanciar la clase y luego llamar los métodos, así por ejemplo:

```
<?php
class Conexion{

  public $conn = null;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","futuro");
  }
}
```

Luego en la parte superior del otro archivo tienes `$objeto=new Conexion;` y debes corregirlo para que se pueda instanciar el objeto, así `$objeto = new Conexion();`

Como ya con eso instancias la clase Conexion, entonces en la línea donde tienes el error debes cambiar el `$this` por `$objeto` quedando así:

```
$enero1 = mysqli_query($objeto->conn, $sql);//$conn variable publica en la clase
```